# Can't change size within layout

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, qdialog

Well, I have a text editor with a button above it... I want the text editor to be inside a layout so that it increases and decreases its size the the `QDialog`, but I don't want to do that same with the button, which, by the way, doesn't have the size that I want and can't change it. What can I do?

**Code:**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
class TextEditorDlg(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.resize(500, 400)
        self.Grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.Grid.addWidget(self.button, 0, 0)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.Grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0)
        self.Grid.addWidget(self.textEdit, 2, 0)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = TextEditorDlg()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**See the problem now?**

Comment: Can you try to be more clear? My *guess* is that you can put the button in a `QHBoxLayout` with some spacers to avoid resizing(see the [`addStretch`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qboxlayout.html#addStretch) method).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all I do not understand why you are using a `QGridLayout`. Do you realize that you are not using the grid at all? You should simply use a `QVBoxLayout`.

Anyway, as I mentioned in a comment, you can probably obtain your desired "output" using a `QHBoxLayout` and the `addStretch` methods:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class TextEditorDlg(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TextEditorDlg, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(500, 400)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)

        self.button_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button_layout.addStretch()
        self.button_layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button_layout.addStretch()

        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)

        self.grid.addLayout(self.button_layout, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.textEdit, 2, 0)

        # Alternative using QVBoxLayout:
        #self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        #self.layout.addLayout(self.button_layout)
        #self.layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        #self.layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = TextEditorDlg()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You can tune the stretch amount passing an integer to [`addStretch`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qboxlayout.html#addStretch).

If you wanted to use a `QGridLayout` to place the button in a specific position, then you should have done something like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class TextEditorDlg(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TextEditorDlg, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(500, 400)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)

        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)

        # Use the row-span and column-span arguments!
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.textEdit, 2, 0, 1, 3)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = TextEditorDlg()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You can place the button exactly where you want using the correct row and column indexes and row-span and column-span values.

---

**Edit:** If you want to change the size of the `QPushButton` you must change the `QSizePolicy` of the button **and** the policy of the `QTextEdit`. For example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class TextEditorDlg(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TextEditorDlg, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(500, 400)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.textEdit.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)

        # Use the row-span and column-span arguments!
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button, 0, 0, 3, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 3, 0, 1, 3)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.textEdit, 4, 0, 1, 3)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = TextEditorDlg()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You'll see that the button is bigger. You can control how big by changing the row-span.
In the line `self.grid.addWidget(self.button, 0, 0, 3, 1)` increasing/decreasing the `3` will increase/decrease the vertical size(actually the number of rows occupied by the widget) and increasing/decreasing the `1` will change the horizontal size.

Note that if you place the widget at row `0` spanning for `3` rows then you have to be carefully to not create collisions adding new widgets to the layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how to do I increase the height of the button in the second example?

Comment: You'll have to play with the row-span of the button **and** the `QTextEdit`. Anyway, as I already stated more than once, using a `QVBoxLayout` would be a lot easier in your situation.